# Android Studio Installation

Tags: android, android-studio

I got an error while installing Android studio.

> The following SDK components were not installed:  source-23,
>   extra-google-m2repository and platform-tools

Retry didn't work, so I canceled and clicked on **Configure** > **SDK Manager**.
It asked me to specify SDK location, although I specified it in the begginning. I clicked **Edit** and chose pre-specified location and clicked **Next** > **Next**.

Got same error.

Comment: see if [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004209/the-following-sdk-components-were-not-installed-sys-img-x86-addon-google-apis)

Comment: May be I should run **$sudo ./studio.sh** I will check after all my downloads are finished..

Comment: Don't use `sudo` to run Android Studio.

Comment: @A.B. -  why? I already did and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, run these two simple commands to install a fresh copy:

---

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make`

`umake android`

---

Interact with the terminal whenever prompted. You can then launch your IDE with this command in the terminal `sh /home/[user]/tools/android/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`. Then, you can also learn how to create a `.desktop` file to run the same command outside terminal. Hopefully, this will get you out of the ocean.

**Important**

1. Replace `[user]` with your username, e.g., `john`.
2. If the solution does not solve your problem, let me know by comments.